# Postgresql - Primary key index getting corrupted after upgrade from 9.2 to 9.6

Tags: postgresql, index, primary-key, upgrade, postgresql-9.2

Im using a Postgresql-9.2 on Centos 6.7. I tried to upgrade the PostgreSQL using --link. After that, I took a table backup and tried to restore this on Dev server. But Im getting an error like,

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "table_pkey"

Then I tried to query the actual database, and I can see the primary key value twice.

And tried to reindex and got this error.

```
WARNING:  concurrent delete in progress within table "table"
ERROR:  could not access status of transaction 3769823
DETAIL:  Could not open file "pg_subtrans/E0B2": No such file or directory.
CONTEXT:  while checking uniqueness of tuple (13075,93) in relation "table"
```

Also disabled the wal log, cleaned the wal log files and reset the xlog.

I just wanted to why happened and how to fix them?